# How can I write this command line command in Perl using the ImageMagick API?

Tags: perl, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

How can I do the same as the following command line command in Perl using the ImageMagick API?

```
convert scotland.jpg[1x1+0+0] -depth 8 txt:
```

The result should look similar to this:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,rgb
0,0: ( 48, 50, 47)  #30322F  rgb(48,50,47)
```

Comment: You should make a list of the things this command does. Then you can go and look that up at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php and apply all the things you need.

Comment: problem is, i am not that much into perlmagick to know what this command does exactly, but i know how to parse the result in order to get the pixel color of the first pixel in my image (that is my goal)

Comment: Do you want to use that in your Perl script, or do you need this text file?

Comment: i want to use it in perl script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an explanation in [Perl & Image::Magick, getting color values by pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681415/perl-imagemagick-getting-color-values-by-pixel) and lifted/changed the code. This works for me:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper; 
use Image::Magick; 

my $img = Image::Magick->new; 
$img->Read("foo.jpg");

my @pixel = $img->GetPixels(
  width  => 1,
  height => 1,
  x      => 0,
  y      => 0,
  map    => "RGB"
);

print Dumper \@pixel;
```

As said by brian in his answer to the linked question, you may need to reduce the depth. See the other question for details.